# Selecting a specific number in Python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I would like to capture **25.43** which is mentioned in bracket as shown below. I am not sure how to do it. I tried slicing it, but it doesn't give the desired output

Please make a note that this number is dynamic and will change often. I am only interested in capturing the number in parentheses.

```
a = [u'\xa0\xa0119\xa0\xa0(25.43)%\xa0\xa0']
```

Comment: What do you mean by select? Is the structure of the string always the same?

Comment: @timgeb, not select but i would want to capture this value in the string. Yes the structure of the string is always same except the number which i have marked in bold.

Comment: Yes @timgeb, Warren Weckesser answer has helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As several of the other answers show, a regular expression can work great.  You could also simply use the `find()` method and slicing:

```
In [9]: s
Out[9]: u'\xa0\xa0119\xa0\xa0(25.43)%\xa0\xa0'

In [10]: s[s.find('(')+1:s.find(')')]
Out[10]: u'25.43'
```

Comment: Your solution worked mate. thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes the structure of the string is always same except the number which i have marked in bold.

Then you can use the following regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> a = [u'\xa0\xa0119\xa0\xa0(25.43)%\xa0\xa0']
>>> re.search(r'\((\d+\.\d+)\)', a[0]).group(1)
u'25.43'
```

This will find the first floating point number in between parentheses in your string.

Note that your `a` is a `list` containing a string, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in this way:

```
a = u'\xa0\xa0119\xa0\xa0(25.43)%\xa0\xa0'
print re.findall('\\xa0\\xa0119\\xa0\\xa0\(' + "(\d+\.\d+)" + '\)%\\xa0\\xa0', a)
```

Using `(\d+\.\d+)` here I am actually capturing the dynamic part that you have mentioned. `\d+` means 1 or more digits. And using the bracket I am actually capturing the decimal number in regex group.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
>>>b = a[0].encode('ascii','ignore')
>>>b
'119(25.43)%'
>>>b.split('(',1)[1].split(')')[0]
'25.43'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first find the brackets then check if the string inside matches a floating number type

```
>>> a = '\xa0\xa0119\xa0\xa0(25.43)%\xa0\xa0'
>>> b = re.findall(r"(\d+\.\d+)",a)
>>> b
['25.43']
```